# php copy file to all the folders

Tags: php, directory

Hi I want to copy a file to all the folders in a directory

my root folder tree is

i want to copy file in root folder to every target folder

folder structure is

[image]

Comment: If the folder structure dynamic or static?

Comment: loop over the folders and subfolders recursively. if the folder is of the kind you want it to be (you don't specify how you spot that. by name perhaps?) copy the file. if not, skip.

Comment: What you tried so far? Before you ask question please try yourself. Where is your coding

Comment: @ aaron W : foder stucture is static

Comment: Look up some of the examples here: http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursivedirectoryiterator.php

Comment: @ Rithu see my code in answer , @ Alex i've tried and solved proble,
i don't know why this stackoverflow guys are voting down and closing the question which must be answer .. :( :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have a static folder structure I'd suggest just storing the different subfolders in an array and loop through that to [`copy`](https://www.php.net/copy) the file

```
$rootpath = ".";
$destpaths = array("/Folder1/Subfolder1/AnotherSubFolder/Target/",
               "/Folder2/Subfolder1/AnotherSubFolder/Target/",
               "/Folder3/Subfolder1/AnotherSubFolder/Target/",
               "/Folder4/Subfolder1/AnotherSubFolder/Target/",
               "/Folder5/Subfolder1/AnotherSubFolder/Target/",
               "/Folder6/Subfolder1/AnotherSubFolder/Target/",
               "/FolderN/Subfolder1/AnotherSubFolder/Target/");
$file = '/example.txt';
$copyfrom = $rootpath . $file;

foreach($destpaths as $destpath)
{
    $copyto = $rootpath . $destpath . $file;
    if (!copy($copyfrom, $copyto)) {
        echo "failed to copy $file";
    }
}
```

**As Aaron W. suggested**
and also used [glob-php](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) to get recursive paths(folder1,folder2...)
i'm placing this code and file same folder and placed that in same root path as folder1,folder2...

```
$rootpath = "..";
$frompath = ".";
$file = '/example.txt';
$tosubpath="/Subfolder1/AnotherSubFolder/Target/";
$copyfrom = $frompath . $file;

listdirs($rootpath,$copyfrom,$tosubpath,$file);


    function listdirs($dir,$copyfrom,$tosubpath,$file) {
        $dirs = glob($dir . '/*', GLOB_ONLYDIR);
    
    foreach($dirs as $destpath)
    {   
        
        $copyto = $destpath. $tosubpath . $file;
        if (!copy($copyfrom, $copyto)) {
            echo "failed to copy ".$copyfrom." to".$copyto."<br>";
        }else{
            echo $copyfrom." copied to".$copyto."<br>";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer.. i have more then 100 folders.. it is better to find another way.

Comment: if there is a pattern to the folder structure you could generate all the folder names with code...otherwise, no.

Comment: i'm trying that only, will post the code after got success with that code